# Hibernate not creating mysql table. No error while running the application

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, microservices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzCa6.png)

Service is created smoothly but no table is created in database.

```
# application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.formate_sql=true;
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MySQL server is up and running on localhost with the default port 3306, and the database named userdb exists , check your Entiy annotated with @Entity
Also, verify that the entity have proper fields and annotations like @Id, @GeneratedValue .